# how to update data using modelformset on django

Tags: django

i'm making  example code to use form and modelformset. create_function is working good. but update_function has a problem. when it call the function occur the error MultiValueDictKeyError. i'dont know how to fix it. please help.

```
def update(request, portfolio_id):
    template_name = 'portfolio_update_form.html'
    pofol = Portfolio.objects.get(id=portfolio_id)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = PortfolioForm(instance=pofol)
        formset = PortfolioImageModelFormSet(

    queryset=PortfolioImage.objects.filter(portfolio__id=portfolio_id), 
        prefix='image'
    )
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = PortfolioForm(request.POST, instance=pofol)
        formset = PortfolioImageModelFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='image')
        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            portfolio = form.save()
            for imageForm in formset:
                pofolImage = imageForm.save(commit=False)
                pofolImage.portfolio = portfolio
                pofolImage.save()
            return redirect('detail', portfolio_id)
    return render(request, template_name, {
        'form' : form, 
        'formset' : formset
    })
```

forms.py

```
PortfolioImageModelFormSet = modelformset_factory(
PortfolioImage,
fields=('image','caption',),
widgets={'caption' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : ''})},
labels={'caption': ''},
extra=1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. You will have to create portfolio_update_form.html and define your create view your_create_view(request,form, template)

```
def update(request, portfolio_id):
    pofol = get_object_or_404(Portfolio, id=portfolio_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PortfolioForm(request.POST, instance=pofol)
    else:
        form = PortfolioForm(instance=pofol)
    return your_create_view(request, form, 'portfolio_update_form.html')
```

Comment: thanks for answer, your code is working. but formset doesn't work. i just added more code. i wanna know what is problem in my update function code.